# Can I send Xbox One output to Google Chromecast?

Tags: xbox-one, hdmi

We've got a great setup right now with a Chromecast plugged into the HDMI port on a projector. It's great to be able to send video from any of our laptops or phones without cables and only have to hit one power button for the projector.

I'd love it if our new Xbox One could also send video through the Chromecast - (as my girlfriend has pointed out a few times) it would be a shame to complicate the uber-simple setup we have right now.

If it sounds like I'm totally ignorant about gaming systems.. yeah well, I'm 36 and this is my first console so you nailed it.

Comment: I know you can beam your Xbox One screen to a Windows 10 PC through the Xbox App.  I'm wondering if you can beam the Xbox to a PC, and then the PC to the chromecast somehow?  I don't have a chromecast to experiment with so I can't say for sure.  Otherwise, I'm only finding articles on the internet about [how you can plug a chromecast into an Xbox](https://www.techjunkie.com/chromecast-xbox-one/) and then beam a phone/other device to it, but that's kind of the opposite of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes you can - I just tested this. However it is extremely laggy as for input lag.  I will put together an answer for you shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OP, originally posted in the question body:

---

> I was able to do this simply by plugging the Chomecast into the HDMI port and then running the "OneGuide" app in Xbox.  In fact, I set it up to display the OneGuide app when I turn on the Xbox because we usually use it more like a TV than a game system.
>
> It's been working seamlessly for about a year now without any other dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: **Yes you can send xbox video through a chromecast, but you need a PC with Windows 10.**

Here are the screenshots / walkthrough on how I set this up.  As I mentioned above, you need a PC running Windows 10, Xbox App logged into on the PC with the same gamertag as on your xbox (comes built in, but be sure to have the latest update), chrome installed, and the chromecast addon installed.

1. Once that is done, click on the Chromecast button in Chrome
   [image]
2. Click on the `Cast to` drop down

[image]

3. Click `Cast Desktop`

[image]

4. The Dropdown should automatical change back to the Chromecast selection page. Note that it should now say `Cast desktop` and click on the desired target chromecast.

[image]

5. Select a dedicated monitor that you want to cast to that Chromecast (I have three monitors currently connected, thats why it shows 3 screens), make sure Share Audio is checked, and then click Share.

[image]

Note: Once you start streaming you will see this on your main monitor and will have the ability to stop streaming that desktop at anytime:

[image]

6. On that same screen that you selected to share to your Chromecast, open the Xbox App, click on the `≡` symbol in the top left to expand the menu, and click on Connection.

[image]

7. Make sure your Xbox is in this list, select Connect, and then Stream. If your Xbox is not on this list, try clicking Add a Device and search for your Xbox (must be on the same network as your PC).  You can have a Xbox controller connected to your PC, but it is not required.  If you don't have a Xbox controller connected to the PC when you click stream, it will give you a message saying one is not connected - just click continue.

[image]

Your Chromecast should now have video and Audio from your Xbox.  As I mentioned in the comments above, this solution has 1-2 seconds of input lag from your controller - not making it a reasonable solution for gaming - however, I did watch a few videos and I did not experience any video / audio syncing issues. Therefore, this is a decent solution for just streaming video from your Xbox (netflix, youtube, etc).

Picture of desktop that is streaming from the Xbox App: 
[image]

Picture of TV that has a Chromecast connected to: 
[image]

Picture of just Chromecast plugged in:
[image]

Comment: Hey @Zero_Stack, would you change the title of your post?  That's a great write-up of how to do this via Windows 10, but a Windows 10 machine _is not required_.

Comment: @doub1ejack: Then add an answer with your solution. The way this site works is people post answers and upvotes help people determine what the best answer is. So if you have a better answer don't ask somebody else to change theirs, just post your better answer.